# how can i invoke a method with generic parameter

Tags: java

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.T;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestJava {

    @Test
    public void testCollect() throws ClassNotFoundException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        String classInterface="Test";
        Class aClass = Class.forName(classInterface);
        Method[] methods = Class.forName(classInterface).getMethods();
        for(Method method : methods) {
            if("batch".equals(method.getName())) {
                List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
                method.invoke(T.class, list );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.T;
public class Test{
    public void batch(T data){
    System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

**I run and get `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.
How can I invoke this method because it will use by others through `classclassPath`.sorry,i use my phone to edit.i copy all code and i also want to ask how to invoke the save method with the parameter such as List**

Comment: Where is `T` declared? If it's a type variable, this code simply won't compile, because `T.class` is illegal. Additionally, the first parameter to `method.invoke` for an instance method should be the instance: that is, an instance of `Test`, not a class.

Comment: Your source code tells us that your code isn't using a generic type. That "T" you are importing ... is just an ordinary java class. Most likely your IDE silently added that import because you started using `T` out of nowhere, and then IDEs sometimes just look if they see a T.class in the project definition. So. Step 1 for learning about generics: read a proper book about generics and understand how you declare/use them.

Comment: So I am not sure if that's what you mean, but if your T parameter is a generic, so not an implemented class but placeholder for other things, your class definition should look like this:
`Class Test<T> {
public void batch(T data){
    System.out.println("success");
    }
}`. Without any import of T. Otherwise I am not sure where do you have a generic parameter.

Comment: `method.invoke(T.class, list)` As mentioned the first argument is wrong, but the second argument is also incorrect. It needs to be an instance of `T` and not a `List<T>` since your method takes `T` as an argument. Step 1 you should be able to create your generic class, and call the method without using reflection at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is pretty bad. There are a lot of information missing, like what is `classInterface`, where is T defined, why is the code flying around in the air and so on. If I copy it, it is not compiling.

But what probably your main issue here is, is that you are giving a class object to the invoke method even though the method is not static.
But if you change the one line to something like

```
method.invoke(new Test(), list );
```

it should work as long as you fix all the other issues, which is hard for me to do here as I don't have the information.

Comment: I am thinking though that `Test` is just an example of the class that will contain method `batch` and they want to call different classes with that method (so to speak, not sure if call in that regard is the best word). So as I understand they want to go through classes and if they meet the `batch` method, they will invoke it. Not sure how to resolve it, cause I feel like I lack the information, but this way might be a wrong approach altogether (not blaming you though, +1 for effort).

Comment: To clarify, I think that the code and question are written in a way that totally support your understanding, this is just my conjecture.